# Web analytics for RSS feeds

Tags: untagged

I've had good results from using Google Analytics to visualize visitors to our web sites. However, GA won't work for RSS feeds since it requires some JavaScript to be embedded into each Web page. Have any of you guys found a Google-like solution for monitoring RSS feed traffic that shows things such as vistor locations displayed on a map ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Feedsqueezer](http://www.feedsqueezer.com/) is an option but it's been in private beta since early 2009 at least.

PostRank offers a [Feed Analytics](http://www.postrank.com/publishers/analytics) service that is also in private beta.

Google acquired [Feedburner](http://feedburner.google.com) which may also fit your needs.

Comment: feedburner is the usual answer

Comment: I recalled recent talk about finding a feedburner replacement because it was languishing since the acquisition. I'm not too familiar with RSS analytics though.